# LDPC: Bit-flipping algorithm (hard-decision message-passing algorithm)

Tags: encoding, decoder, forwarderrorcorrection

I am working with LDPC in which I want to know whether `Bit-flipping algorithm` detects more than one error bit. I have already gone through the LDPC tutorials and video lecture of decoding concept. But still I am not clear.

I need to implement `LDPC decoder` to correct more than one error bits using `hard-decision message-passing algorithm`. So, please anyone explain me what I need to do to correct more than one error bit. I need logic to implement the LDPC. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution for my question itself. It's all depend on size of `codeword` of `H` matrix and `Hamming distance`.

Comment: I think it will be good to share your solution to benefit others who will have the same problem.